# ts-node app running using docker run but not docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```
docker build -t ts-node-api .    
docker run -it --entrypoint sh --expose 3000 -it ts-node-api
```

or

```
docker run --expose 3000 -it steve/ts-node-api
```

works correctly, apart from not connected to the db, which is a later problem.

However, run the same Dockerfile as such:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  ts-node-api:
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: services/ts-node-api/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
```

using docker compose results in:

```
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN npm run build                                                                                                               0.3s
------                                                                                                                                               
 > [6/6] RUN npm run build:
#9 0.244 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#9 0.244 npm ERR! syscall open
#9 0.244 npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
#9 0.245 npm ERR! errno -2
#9 0.246 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
#9 0.246 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#9 0.246 npm ERR! enoent 
#9 0.248 
#9 0.249 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#9 0.249 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-26T18_29_26_477Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your two build setups are different.  The `docker build` command you show is equivalent to

```yaml
build:
  context: .
  # dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

which has a shorthand

```yaml
build: .
```

If the Compose file is in an ancestor directory of the service, so you `cd` into that subdirectory and then run the `docker build .` command, you need to use that subdirectory name as the context directory

```yaml
build: services/ts-node-api
```

The Compose block you show is equivalent to

```bash
docker build -f services/ts-node-api/Dockerfile .
```

which causes `COPY` commands to be interpreted relative to the root of your tree, not the directory containing your application (compare the two `context:` directories), which is why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thank you David, that has worked and left me with a better understanding. Now to work out getting the app and db to talk!